# If Page is idle for sometime any postback leads to whole page refresh in UpdatePanel

Tags: 2013, visual-web-part, updatepanel

Within the solution there are two webparts, second is being shown within a modal dialog in first webpart.

In second webpart everything is inside update panel(bad practice).
When I open the second webpart first time and perform any postback(either by button click or dropdown index change)

Page.IsPostBack is true and ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack is also true (Which is good because within page load I have added check for these two condition)

but when I keep the modal popup static for lets say 3 minutes and then perform any postback operation both the Page.IsPostBack and ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack are false hence instead of firing the event handler for the control causing the postback the whole page within the modal refreshes.

Update panel is used like this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
....contents
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel
```

Triggers are not used.
tried these attribute as well

```
ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional"
```

still the same behavior

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out this was the problem with SharePoint 2013 and update panel
You can read about the exact problem and available workarounds in the following technet forum:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/systemcenter/en-US/c33d4a46-87d6-4dbc-a24c-cb8e5f9eb1ea/page-refresh-after-postback-from-updatepanel-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment

among the multiple workaround suggested the one works for me is the following script:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilBodyLoaded(function () {
    try {
        if (Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().digestFixed !== true) {
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().digestFixed = true;
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(function () {
                if (typeof (UpdateFormDigest) === "function" && typeof (_spPageContextInfo) === "object")
                    UpdateFormDigest(_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl, 3 * 60 * 1000);
            });
        }
    }
    catch (e) { }
});
```

Thanks @Shai Petel (From the forum)

Comment: If there is a possibility, we can disable the form authentication for the web application, that also resolves the issue.